# drop event is not fired

Tags: drag-and-drop, dart

In the application below, the drop method is never called. The drop target (`div2`)  is indicated by cancelling event in dragEnter and dragOver events but drop is not triggered. HTML and .dart are as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Dandd</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="dandd.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Drag and drop</h1>

<p>Hello world from Dart!</p>
<div>
  <label id='lbl' draggable='true'  style='border: 1px solid; '>div1</label>
 </div>
<p></p>

<div id='div2'>
  <label>div2</label>
 </div>
<script type="application/dart" src='dandd.dart > </script>
<script type='text/javascript'  
   src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is dart file

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  query('#lbl')
    ..on.dragStart.add(onDragStart)
    ..on.dragEnd.add(onDragEnd);

  query('#div2')
    ..on.dragEnter.add(onDragEnter)
    ..on.dragOver.add(onDragOver)
    ..on.drop.add(onDrop);

  query('#div2')
    ..on.dragLeave.add(onDragLeave);
}

onDragStart(MouseEvent e) {
  print('started');
  var lbl = e.target as LabelElement;
  lbl.style.opacity = '0.4';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', lbl.id);
}

onDragEnd(MouseEvent e) {
 var lbl = e.target as LabelElement;
 lbl.style.opacity = '1.0';
 print('drag end called');
}

onDragEnter(MouseEvent e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
  var x = e.target as DivElement;
  x.classes.add('blueborder');
}

onDragOver(MouseEvent e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
  var x = e.target as DivElement;
  x.classes.add('blueborder');
}

onDragLeave(MouseEvent e) {
  var x = e.target as DivElement;
  x.classes.remove('blueborder');
}

onDrop(MouseEvent e){
  print('on drop called');
  var x = e.target as DivElement;
  x.classes.remove('blueborder');
  String sid = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  var v = query('#{sid}');
  x.children.add(v);
}
```

Comment: issue appears fixed now. Users who are still seeing this should make sure they're calling preventDefault and setting a dropEffect in onDragOver (doing it in onDragEnter won't work)

Comment: Sorry for pushing this old question but I have the ams problem. Even setting e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy"; in onDragOver and calling e.preventDefault() on onDrag and returning false does not help. Even when compiled into JavaScript- Can you give me an working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug. See [issue 6646](http://dartbug.com/6646).